# How to catch keyboard events on an inline element in a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, keyboard-events, flowdocument

I need to catch keyboard events on an `Inline` element (`System.Windows.Documents.Run`). In the example below all the mouse events works but none of the keyboard events.

Why are no keyboard events firing?

```
private Run CreateWord(string text)
{
    var word = new Run(text);

    // Works as expected
    word.MouseDown += Word_MouseDown;
    word.MouseEnter += Word_MouseEnter;
    word.MouseLeave += Word_MouseLeave;

    // Does not work. No keyboard events are fired
    word.PreviewKeyUp += Word_KeyUp;
    word.KeyDown += Word_KeyDown;
    word.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(delegate (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AddHandler KeyDown");
    }), true);

    return word;
}

private void Word_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("KeyDown");
}

private void Word_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("KeyUp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there with the AddHandler. You just need to call `AddHandler` on the `RichTextBox` control.

The `RichTextBox` is handling the `KeyDown` event, so the event isn't reaching your `Run`.

Something like this...

```
private Run CreateWord(string text)
{
    var word = new Run(text);

    // Works as expected
    word.MouseDown += Word_MouseDown;
    word.MouseEnter += Word_MouseEnter;
    word.MouseLeave += Word_MouseLeave;

    RichTextBox.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(delegate (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"AddHandler KeyDown - {word.Text}");
    }), true);

    return word;
}
```

Comment: Testing this a bit more I'm not sure this will work for you. If you start editing the contents of the RichTextBox it can split the Run into two, the original run will continue to work but the new one wont have the handler attached.

Comment: I think the behavior with the split of the `Run` has to do with different language settings of the `RichTextBox` and the current input (OS) language. I had this problem earlier but solved it by setting the language. I haven't been able to try you solution yet but it looks promising. I'll mark it as an answer if it works!

Comment: The CreateWord function is called repeatedly for all words in a text. With the suggested solution the `KeyDown` event of the `RichTextBox` will fire 10 times if there are 10 words. Also, I can't t find the originating `Run` in the parameters of the event. I can't get this solution to work.